# how to check and uncheck checkbox in nested array in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I used a checkbox in a nested array. Its onclick checkbox Boolean value is changed into true false but my checkbox is not checked and unchecked.

Here is the code for the checkbox used in scrollView....

```js
<ScrollView
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
  style={{ backgroundColor: '#e7e7e7', }}>
  {this.state.ExampleQuestions.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
        <Card style={{
          flexDirection: 'column',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          padding: 10
        }}>

          <View style={styles.oval}>
            <Text numberOfLines={10} style={styles.welcome}>
              ({index + 1})- {item.question_description.toString().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")}
            </Text>
          </View>

          {item.question_type == 2 &&
            item.answers.map((itemtwo, indextwo) => {
              itemtwo.status = ""
              console.log('status', itemtwo.status)
              return (
                <View style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  alignItems: 'center', margin: 5, padding: 8,
                  elevation: 1, borderRadius: 5, borderWidth: 0.7,
                  borderColor: '#C9C9C9',
                }}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 0.15, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <CheckBox checked={itemtwo.status}
                      onPress={() => {
                        itemtwo.status!=itemtwo.status
                        this.CheckBox(item, itemtwo, index, indextwo)
                        console.log("render status", itemtwo.status)
                      }} />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column', }}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={10} style={{
                      fontSize: 15, paddingEnd: 5,
                      fontWeight: '500', textAlign: 'left',
                      fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? Fonts.SanFranciscoDisplay_Medium : 'roboto_medium',
                      color: "black"
                    }}>{itemtwo.answer_options.toString().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>

              )
            })

          }
```

Checkbox Checked and Unchecked Function is as follows..

```js
CheckBox(item, itemtwo, index, indextwo) {

    console.log(item, itemtwo, index, indextwo)
    console.log(itemtwo.status)


        item.answers.map((itemnew,indexnew)=>{
          if(itemnew.answer_options==itemtwo.answer_options){
            itemtwo.status = !itemtwo.status
            if(itemtwo.status==true){
            const answerValue=this.state.ExampleQuestions[index].answers[indexnew].answer_options
            this.state.ExampleQuestions[index].answers.find(v => v.answer_options == answerValue).status = true
            console.log('selected:' , itemtwo.status + itemtwo.answer_options)
            return itemtwo.status
          }
          else if (itemtwo.status==""){
            const answerValue=this.state.ExampleQuestions[index].answers[indexnew].answer_options
            this.state.ExampleQuestions[index].answers.find(v => v.answer_options == answerValue).status = ""
            console.log('unselected:' ,itemtwo.status + itemtwo.answer_options)
            return itemtwo.status
          }

        }
        })
    console.log('Final array checked', this.state.ExampleQuestions)
  }
```

My Array is Here:

```js
(5) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
answers: (4) […]
​​​
0: Object { answer_options: "4", is_answer: true, status: "" }
​​​
1: Object { answer_options: "5", is_answer: "", status: true }
​​​
2: Object { answer_options: "6", is_answer: "", status: true }
​​​
3: Object { answer_options: "7", is_answer: true, status: true }
​​​
length: 4
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
marks: 2
​​
q_id: 209
​​
question_description: "<p>WHAT IS THE ANSWER OF 2+2?</p>\n"
​​
question_type: 2
```

Following is the Array of Data. I want to check and uncheck checkbox using inner array value called Status.

Its value is changing on click checkbox but checkbox is not checked and unchecked. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for multi selection checkbox

```
_onItemSelectDeselect(item, index) {

        let selecedItemDict = item
        if (selecedItemDict.isSelected) {
            selecedItemDict.isSelected = false
        } else {
            selecedItemDict.isSelected = true
        }
        let defectiveParts = this.state.defectivePartsList
        defectiveParts[index] = selecedItemDict

        this.setState({
            defectivePartsList: defectiveParts
        })

    }

<FlatList


 numColumns={2}
                    data={this.state.defectivePartsList}
                        extraData={this.state}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.type}
                        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, padding: 0 }} onPress={() => this._onDefectiveItemSelectDeselect(item, index)}>
                                <View style={{ borderWidth: 0, height: 40, flexDirection: 'row' }} >

                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `react-native-check-box` which accepts checked as `boolean` and also supports image for checked and unchecked.

I have a list like this

```
state = {
 array = [
  {
    text: "first text",
    checked: false, 
  },
  {
   text: "first text",
   checked: false, 
  }
  ]
}
```

Here I am using a `FlatList`

```
<FlatList
  data={list.items}
  contentContainerStyle={{ marginRight: 15 }}
  renderItem={(obj: Object) => ListRow(obj.item, obj.index,
    () => onChange(obj.item, obj.index))}
/>
```

My `ListRow` looks like this, In list row, I am updating the listArray in the state. Which re-runs the render method and list gets updated.

```
const ListRow = (item: Object, index: number, onSelect: Function) => (
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
  <View key={item.id} style={styles.checkListRow} >
    <CheckBox
    style={styles.checkBoxStyle}
    onClick={onSelect} // here I am updating the checked attribute of listArray
    isChecked={item.done}
    checkedImage={<Image source={checkedBox} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />}
    unCheckedImage={<Image source={greyBox} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />}
  />
  <View style={styles.itemLabelContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.itemLabelStyle}>
      {/* {item.name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1, item.name.length)} */}
      {item.name || 'Chicken'}
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.quantityText}>Qty: {item.qty} {item.unit || null}</Text>
  </View>
</View>
</View>
)
```